# How to make button in a register/sign up screen inactive until the textfield is filled properly with the appropriate information in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, mobile

I created a sign up screen and I used a pageview in it. That page view has a controller and that controller also works with a smooth page indicator I added. The page view is also connected to a button I created using a container I designed wrapped in a gesture detector. The page changes to the next when the button is pressed and finally on the last page the button signs up the user. I want the button to be inactive and designed differently on all pages until the condition are met.

1. The first page requires an email
2. The second page requires a password
3. The third page is to confirm the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the onPressed Callback of a button to null and the button will be disabled.

```
...
onPressed: condition_is_met ? (){} : null,
...
```